# Liferay Deployment

Tags: tomcat, liferay

I am trying to deploy few liferay portlets in my local and I keep getting this exception. 
Here is the log of the error:

"classLoader findResourceInternal INFO: Illegal access: this web application instance has been stopped already.

Could not load META-INF/services/org.apache.axis.EngineConfigurationFactory. The eventual following stack trace is caused by an error thrown for debugging purposes as well as to attempt to terminate the thread which caused the illegal access, and has no functional impact.

ERROR [ContainerBackgroundProcessor[StandardEngine[Catalina]]][PortalClassLoaderServlet:79] javax.servlet.ServletException: java.lang.NullPointerException"

Comment: Need more information - *exact* Liferay version, and code, best an [MCVE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Comment: Liferay 6.1, I cannot upload the code.